# SQL exception preparing query with ORMLite

Tags: java, sql, exception, h2, ormlite

I am using an ORM (ORMlite) and all my calls are going well until I get the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
>       SELECT * FROM ""STORIES"" WHERE ""TITLE"" = 'Deepcut case leads 'NOT FOLLOWED[*]''  "; SQL statement:
>       SELECT * FROM `Stories` WHERE `title` = 'Deepcut case leads 'not followed''  [42000-152]
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:179)
>           at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:480)
>           at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:229)
>           at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:426)
>           at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:374)
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1093)
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:601)
>           at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:83)
>           at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedPreparedStmt.compile(MappedPreparedStmt.java:44)
>           at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:169)
>           at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:119)
>           at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:189)

I'm confused as to whats going wrong. I am calling the search from these lines:

```
// get our query builder from the DAO
QueryBuilder<Story, Integer> queryBuilder = StoryDao.queryBuilder();
// the 'title' field must be equal to title (a variable)
queryBuilder.where().eq(Story.TITLE_FIELD_NAME, title);
// prepare our sql statement
PreparedQuery<Story> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
// query for all stories that have that title
List<Story> accountList = StoryDao.query(preparedQuery);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Syntax error in SQL statement " SELECT * FROM ""STORIES"" WHERE ""TITLE""...

@bemace is correct that there seem to be quotes in the title that is screwing up the escaping of strings generated by the query.

In ORMLite, you should use the `SelectArg` feature which will generate a query with SQL ? arguments and then pass the string to the prepared statement directly.

See the [documentation on the `SelectArg`](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg).  With it, you'd do something like:

```
QueryBuilder<Story, Integer> queryBuilder = StoryDao.queryBuilder();
SelectArg titleArg = new SelectArg();
queryBuilder.where().eq(Story.TITLE_FIELD_NAME, titleArg);
PreparedQuery<Story> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
titleArg.setValue(title);
List<Story> accountList = StoryDao.query(preparedQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of guessing but it looks like there's a problem with the value in the `title` field, maybe an unescaped quote mark?

I'm not familiar with ORMLite but `title = 'Deepcut case leads 'not followed''` doesn't look right.  Should probably be `"Deepcut case leads 'not followed'"` or `'Deepcut case leads \'not followed\''` or some such.

Comment: Using double quotes or backslash will not work on H2 as it follows the SQL standard. Which means that string literals need to be enclosed in single quotes and to embed another quote you need to use two single quotes: `'Deepcut case leads ''not followed'`

Comment: Yes, 'Deepcut case leads ''not followed' is correct according to the SQL standard. All SQL databases support this.

Comment: More details: `'Deepcut case leads ''not followed'''` is correct according to the SQL standard. All SQL databases support this. `"Deepcut case leads 'not followed'"` is a quoted identifier, again according to the SQL standard (but I guess there is no such column name). `'Deepcut case leads \'not followed\''` is illegal according to the SQL standard, but supported by MySQL and PostgreSQL if SQL compatibility is disabled.

Comment: Is there a way to make java auto escape my strings? or should I write it myself?

Comment: @Alex: use a PreparedStatement and you don't have to worry about things like that

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for the statement would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Stories WHERE title = 'Deepcut case leads ''not followed'' ';
```

Note the duplicated single quotes inside the string literal.

You will need to tell your ORM layer to follow the ANSI SQL rules for literals.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that there is some syntactical problem with your generated SELECT statement. Can you print out the generated query? Doing that might help you pin down the exact issue here.

EDIT: Looking closely at your trace shows that string escaping is not handled properly here. Is this your own QueryBuilder? Also, as per [this link](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#SEC30), are you using `SelectArg` or directly setting the title?