# Ormlite escape string method?

Tags: android, sql, string, escaping, ormlite

Is there a native way of escaping strings for Ormlite for Android?

For example, if I want to supply a string: ormlite's escape func, it needs to be supplied as ormlite\'s escape func.

```
TestDao.queryForFirst(TestDao.queryBuilder().where().like("stats", stats)
    .prepare())
```

I tried using UpdateBuilder's escapeValue method, but it only makes the following change:
'ormlite's escape func'. It adds single quotes to beginning and end of the statement. Is there a native support for escaping strings to be sql injection safe?

If not, what are the ways to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: May the first string in ``like()``-Method be a potential injection-security lack?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I tried using UpdateBuilder's escapeValue method, but it only makes the following change: 'ormlite's escape func'. It adds single quotes to beginning and end of the statement. Is there a native support for escaping strings to be sql injection safe?

This is a FAQ.   The proper way to do this is to use a `SelectArg` argument so the SQL can use a ? type of construct.  Here's another [question talking about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280227/sql-exception-preparing-query-with-ormlite/5284144#5284144).

```
SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg(stats);
TestDao.queryForFirst(
    TestDao.queryBuilder().where().like("stats", selectArg).prepare());
```

Here's the documentation on the [select-arg functionality](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg).

**Edit:**

As @Moritz points out, if you are actually updating the database, you can also use the `SelectArg` with the `UpdateBuilder`:

```
SelectArg arg = new SelectArg("Some value");
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(MY_COLUMN, arg);
```

Comment: BTW this also works for update statements: 
`SelectArg arg = new SelectArg();
arg.setValue("Some value");
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(MY_COLUMN, arg);`