# ORMLite query with quote, Android

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite, with the Table RecentSearch :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = LocalStorageConfig.SQL_RECENTS_TABLE_NAME)
public class RecentSearch {

    @DatabaseField
    public String search_text;
    public static String SQL_SEARCH_FIELD = "search_text";

    @DatabaseField
    public String location_text;
    public static String SQL_LOCATION_FIELD = "location_text";

    @DatabaseField
    public Date creation_date = new Date();
    public static String SQL_CREATION_DATE_FIELD = "creation_date";
```

It's working almost all the time, but when I discover the case with a String containing a ', then it appears to be a problem. Do you know how to solve this ? I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Here is my function to delete a recent

```
public boolean deleteRecent(RecentSearch search) {
    try {
        Dao<RecentSearch, Integer> recentsDao = recentsSqlManager.getRecentsDao();
        DeleteBuilder<RecentSearch, Integer> deleteBuilder = recentsDao.deleteBuilder();

        deleteBuilder.where().eq(RecentSearch.SQL_SEARCH_FIELD, search.getSearch_text()).and().eq(RecentSearch.SQL_LOCATION_FIELD, search.location_text);
        recentsDao.delete(deleteBuilder.prepare());
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Database exception", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception i get :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android statement: DELETE FROM `recent_searches` WHERE (`search_text` = '' AND `location_text` = 'Villefranche-d'Allier, Allier' ) 
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runUpdate(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:66)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.delete(StatementExecutor.java:425)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.delete(BaseDaoImpl.java:347)
...
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Allier": syntax error: , while compiling: DELETE FROM `recent_searches` WHERE (`search_text` = '' AND `location_text` = 'Villefranche-d'Allier, Allier' ) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280227/sql-exception-preparing-query-with-ormlite and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400782/ormlite-escape-string-method

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> when I discover the case with a String containing a ' (single quote), then it appears to be a problem.

In [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), when you are trying to build a query with quotes, you should use the `SelectArg` feature which will generate a query with SQL `?` arguments and then pass the string to the prepared statement directly.  This gets around any problems with escaping of special characters as well as protects you from SQL injection security issues.  See the [documentation on `SelectArg`](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg).

With `SelectArg`, you'd do something like:

```
DeleteBuilder<RecentSearch, Integer> deleteBuilder = recentsDao.deleteBuilder();

// create our argument which uses a SQL ?
SelectArg locationArg = new SelectArg(search.location_text);
deleteBuilder.where().eq(RecentSearch.SQL_SEARCH_FIELD, search.getSearch_text())
    .and().eq(RecentSearch.SQL_LOCATION_FIELD, locationArg);
recentsDao.delete(deleteBuilder.prepare());
...
```

Comment: First, thanks for your explanations, everytime I have a doubt related to ORMLite, you have already answered here. I was wondering, is there any difference between: 

recentsDao.delete(deleteBuilder.prepare()); 

and 

deleteBuilder.delete(); ?

Comment: No different @AlvaroSantisteban.  The .delete() is just a call through to make it easier.  It says so in the javadocs: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/DeleteBuilder.html#delete()

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SelectArg](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#SEC38) object when binding to your query as this will escape any quotes so they don't generate invalid sql.